# How to Change Trace Visibility When Restyling Multiple Data Attributes in R Plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm working on creating an app to demonstrate a mathematical function to find the primes. Since I wanted an element of interactivity, I decided to take this as an opportunity to try out Plotly. The plot is to have a button interface that will allow users the ability to view how each step of the function contributes to the overall output. The `data.frame` used can be generated using the code below:

```
x_values <- seq(0.01, 10, by = 0.01)

df <- data.frame(x = x_values)

# calculate each step
df$factorial <- factorial(df$x - 1) + 1
df$division <- df$factorial / df$x
df$multiplication <- df$division * pi
df$cosine <- cos(df$multiplication)
df$squaring <- df$cosine ^ 2
df$y <- floor(df$squaring)
```

For the plot, I wanted it to be formatted so as to properly mark the holes and jumps present within the floored output. Assuming of course that I mark the original trace as invisible, the below code achieves the desired effect:

```
# Create plot
p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  
  # Add traces for the continuous segments
  add_trace(data = df[-(jump_indices), ],
            x = ~x, y = ~y,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%

  # Add closed circles for the jumps
  add_trace(data = df[jump_indices, ],
            x = ~x, y = ~y,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(symbol = "circle", size = 8, color = "#1f77b4",
                          line = list(color = "#1f77b4", width = 1),
                          opacity = 1),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%

  
  # Add open circles for the holes
  add_trace(data = df[jump_indices, ],
            x = ~x, y = ~y - 1,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
            marker = list(symbol = "circle-open", size = 8, color = "#1f77b4",
                          line = list(color = "#1f77b4", width = 1),
                          opacity = 1),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%

   # Apply theme
  {do.call(layout, c(list(.), plotly_theme))}
```

The issue arises when trying to implement the necessary button logic. I need to both swap the plotted y value and change the currently visible traces when the corresponding button is pressed. Below is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
# Add buttons for each step of the function
p <- p %>% 
  config(displayModeBar = F) %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        bgcolor = "#1e2124",
        activebgcolor = "#bbbbbb",
        font = list(color = "#1f77b4"),
        
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$y)),
                           list("visible" = list(F, T, T, T))),
               label = "After Floor"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$squaring)),
                           list("visible" = list(T, F, F, F))),
               label = "After Squaring"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$cosine)),
                           list("visible" = list(T, F, F, F))),
               label = "After Cosine"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$multiplication)),
                           list("visible" = list(T, F, F, F))),
               label = "After Multiplication"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$division)),
                           list("visible" = list(T, F, F, F))),
               label = "After Division"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list(list("y" = list(df$factorial)),
                           list("visible" = list(T, F, F, F))),
               label = "After Factorial")
        ),
        direction = "right",
        pad = list(r = 10, t = 10),
        showactive = TRUE,
        x = -0.1,
        xanchor = "left",
        y = 1,
        yanchor = "bottom"
      )
   )
)
```

Whilst the y values do swap, the traces I've attempted to hide are still visible. In the case of this plot, that means the holes and jumps are present on all graphs.

I've no doubt that I've missed something fairly fundamental when it comes to setting the visibility of the traces, but I haven't been able to narrow down on exactly where my issue lies. If anyone sees my error, I'd greatly appreciate any advice you can give.

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! You did a great job of writing your question. Unfortunately, it is not reproducible, which is probably why no one has answered it yet. What is `jump_indices`? What is `plotly_theme`?  When you run `p <- plotly_build(p); length(p$x$data)` what value does it return? If it returns anything other than 4, then you're missing `T` or `F`'s necessary for each button. If it does return 4, then the assumed order of your traces might be the issue. For a better answer, make your question reproducible.